# LayoutAnchorablePane binding to items

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use LayoutAnchorablePane and add the pane children in code behind as below

```
<ad:LayoutAnchorablePane DockHeight="Auto" x:Name="LeftTools">
</ad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
```

In code behind I add its children

```
dockSite = new LayoutAnchorable();
LeftTools.Children.Add((LayoutAnchorable)dockSite);
```

Is there any way to bind this? I have done this in my VM

```
// In Constructor
ObservableCollection<LayoutAnchorable> LeftToolList = new ObservableCollection<LayoutAnchorable>();

// Property
public ObservableCollection<LayoutAnchorable> LeftToolList { get; set; }
```

But how do I bind into xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl` to show the items in your collection, but tell it which panel type to use.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LeftToolList}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <ad:LayoutAnchorablePane/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```